# how to resolve ExpatParser$parseException

Tags: java

i get the following result from my dot net web service

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <DataTable xmlns="http://www.mkttech.in/">
- <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
- <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="RecordSet" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
- <xs:element name="RecordSet">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
- <xs:element name="USERNAME" minOccurs="0">
- <xs:simpleType>
- <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:maxLength value="51" /> 
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="PWD_EXPIRY" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="FLDPWDMINLENGTH" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="FLDPWDMAXLENGTH" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="FLDMAXATTEMPT" type="xs:short" minOccurs="0" /> 
- <xs:element name="LOG_REASON" minOccurs="0">
- <xs:simpleType>
- <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:maxLength value="200" /> 
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="EXCH_SEG" msdata:ReadOnly="true" minOccurs="0">
- <xs:simpleType>
- <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:maxLength value="51" /> 
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
- <xs:element name="SEGMENTDESC" minOccurs="0">
- <xs:simpleType>
- <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:maxLength value="100" /> 
  </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  </xs:element>
- <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
- <DocumentElement xmlns="">
- <RecordSet diffgr:id="RecordSet1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <USERNAME /> 
  <PWD_EXPIRY>0</PWD_EXPIRY> 
  <FLDPWDMINLENGTH>2</FLDPWDMINLENGTH> 
  <FLDPWDMAXLENGTH>8</FLDPWDMAXLENGTH> 
  <FLDMAXATTEMPT>100</FLDMAXATTEMPT> 
  <LOG_REASON>INVALID PASSWORD...</LOG_REASON> 
  <EXCH_SEG>NSE-CAPITAL</EXCH_SEG> 
  <SEGMENTDESC>NSE Capital Market</SEGMENTDESC> 
  </RecordSet>
  </DocumentElement>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
  </DataTable>
```

i am using SoapObject to recieve this response.
next i was parsing this using the xmlpullparser. 
i followed the following  [Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)

but i am getting following exception when nextTag() is executed

org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Error parsing document. (position:line -1, column -1) caused by: org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser$ParseException: At line 1, column 7: not well-formed (invalid token)

i am new to both android and java. i really need help.
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There should be no spaces before `<?xml version="1.0"...` .Check with this online App for [XML/XSD Validation](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! :) the xml is not well formed. I'll hit back with further development(or errors)..